# WCF + REST: Automated support available for hyperlinks to related resources?

Tags: wcf, rest

In RESTful web services it is seen as best practice to include hyperlinks to related resources in the response rather than the related resource itself or just the ID.<sup>1</sup>

How to do this in WCF? Is there any support for that? I wouldn't like creating those URLs by hand.

---

<sup>1</sup> See for example http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/rest-design-guidelines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RESTful support for WCF but I'm not sure if there's a way for you to programmatically generate hyperlinks to the resource URLs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx#id0070034

An alternative is to forego WCF altogether and just write the service as an asp.net MVC project and you can use the routing engine to generate your URLs

Comment: Thanks. I know about the REST support in WCF, but haven't figured out how to achieve the goal with the links, hence the question. Could you elaborate a bit on the ASP.NET MVC part of your answer?

Comment: I think ASP.NET Web API is the way to go here. It is possible to create an attribute that automatically sets the link. See [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Contact-Manager-Web-API-0e8e373d) for an example. The ContactSelfLinkFilter class is the interesting part.